# Delete elements during loop awk semantics

Tags: awk, posix, semantics

If we assume the loop returns k==0 first (this order is implementation dependent according to the spec). How many times should the loop body run?  Once or twice? If twice what should be printed for arr[1]?

```
BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero"; 
  arr[1] = "one"; 
  for (k in arr) { 
      print "key " k " val " arr[k]; 
      delete arr[k+1]  
  }
}
```

```
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
....
$ gawk 'BEGIN { arr[0] = "zero"; arr[1] = "one"; for (k in arr) { print "key " k " val " arr[k]; delete arr[k+1]  } }'
key 0 val zero
key 1 val
```

```
$ goawk --version
v1.19.0
$ goawk 'BEGIN { arr[0] = "zero"; arr[1] = "one"; for (k in arr) { print "key " k " val " 
key 0 val zero
```

gnu-awk runs it twice with `arr[1] == ""` and goawk runs it once. Mawk (mawk 1.3.4 20200120) sorts keys 1,0 but has the same fundamental behavior as gnu-awk, looping twice and print the empty string for the deleted key). What is the posix defined expected behavior of this program?

Essentially should keys deleted in past loops appear in future loops?

Comment: I would not expect a consistent order that was not external enforced say with a for loop on integer as keys. in gawk you could use 'asort' and 'asorti' instead of building your own order enforcing code. I barley touch the others so someone will have to chime in for them.

Comment: @tomc that is not the question. The question is assuming the keys come up in the 0, 1 order should the loop be executed twice (even though key 1 is deleted in iteration 0).

Comment: Sounds like undefined behavior to me. Why do you assume there is a spec for this?

Comment: @tripleee That does seem reasonable to me. I was hoping to hear an argument that it is or it isn't, or perhaps a link to some part of the spec I had missed.

Comment: seems like you think the loop should re-evaluate the array conditions such as length every iteration instead of just once at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_09):

> The results of adding new elements to array within such a for loop are
> undefined

but it doesn't define what happens if you delete them other than:

> The delete statement shall remove an individual array element

However, according to [the GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array):

> As a point of information, gawk sets up the list of elements to be iterated over before the loop starts, and does not change it. But not all awk versions do so.

so the behavior is undefined by POSIX, defined for GNU AWK, and you'd have to check the man page for every other AWK to see what it does.

Decide which behavior you want and then to get that behavior robustly and portably in all awks you could write whichever one of these you want:

1. `gawk`s behavior:

```
BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero"; 
  arr[1] = "one"; 
  for (k in arr) { 
      indices[k]
  }
  for (k in indices) { 
      print "key " k " val " arr[k]; 
      delete arr[k+1]  
  }
}
```

2. `goawk`s apparent behavior from your example:

```
BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero"; 
  arr[1] = "one"; 
  for ( k in arr ) {
      indices[k]
  }
  for (k in indices) {
      if ( k in arr ) {
          print "key " k " val " arr[k]; 
          delete arr[k+1]  
      }
  }
}
```

***Notes on your code in general***:

1. `for ( k in ... )` could visit the indices in any order so relying on `delete arr[k+1]` to delete an element of `arr[]` isn't robust as, for example, you might be trying to delete an index past the end of the array on your first iteration through the loop if `in` decides to start with `k` set to the last index in the array.
2. All builtin and generated awk arrays, fields, and strings start at index `1`, not `0`, so don't create your own arrays starting at `0`, start them at `1` to avoid having to remember which type of array it is when writing code to visit the indices and inevitably tripping over that difference at some point.

Comment: Hey ed thanks for the answer. A clearer/more robust example is `BEGIN { arr[1] = 1; arr[2] = 2; arr[3] = 3; for (k in arr} { print "loop ran"; delete arr[1]; delete arr[2]; delete arr[3]; } }`. (Printing 1 vs 3 times). I gave the example above since that's where I encountered the differing behavior.

Comment: You're welcome. I assume you're providing a new example in your comment because you have a followup question - if so please just ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

apparently `mawk-1` is rather unique in this aspect :

> `mawk 1.3.4`

```
% mawk 'BEGIN { 
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
```

> ```
>  key 1 val one     <<<<<<
>  key 0 val zero
> ```

Furthermore, setting the `WHINY_USERS` shell environment flag changes its behavior (an entirely value-less declaration already suffices) :

```
 WHINY_USERS= mawk 'BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
key 0 val zero
key 1 val 

%  mawk 'BEGIN { 
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
key 1 val one
key 0 val zero
```

> `mawk-2 (beta-1.9.9.6)`

```
% mawk2 'BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
key 0 val zero
key 1 val
```

> `gawk 5.2.0`

```
gawk -e 'BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
key 0 val zero
key 1 val
```

> `nawk 20200816`

```
% nawk 'BEGIN {
  arr[0] = "zero";
  arr[1] = "one";
  for (k in arr) {
      print "key " k " val " arr[k];
      delete arr[k+1]
  }
}'
key 0 val zero
```